# Can't Bind to Broadcast Address in Client -- Java/Scala

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp, bind

I'm trying to write a simple UDP heartbeat to broadcast to all listening nodes on a given port throughout my subnet.

I'm having trouble creating/binding the client DatagramSocket.  I'm trying code like this:

```
// My IP is 192.168.201.57, so I'm using 192.168.201.255 for broadcast.  Right?
val socket = new DatagramSocket(9099, InetAddress.getByName("192.168.201.255"))
```

This produced an exception: java.net.BindException: Can't assign requested address.

I've also tried 255.255.255.255 with the same result. 
Also tried something like this based on something I read in another post:

```
val socket = new DatagramSocket(null)
socket.bind( new InetSocketAddress(broadcastIp, port) )  // where I tried several broadcastIp values
```

This also gave the same exception.  I should also add that I've tried different port values and made sure nothing else on the machine is using the ports I'm trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I usually used:

```
public static final String HOST_DST = "148.140.60.29";
public static final int    PORT_DST = 2416;
public static final int    PORT_SRC = 2802;

void method() {
   DatagramSocket    sock    = new DatagramSocket( PORT_SRC );
   InetSocketAddress dst     = new InetSocketAddress( HOST_DST, PORT_DST );
   ByteBuffer        message = ByteBuffer.allocate( MESSAGE_SIZE );
   for(...) {
      message.clear();
      message.putFloat( ... );
      message.putInt( ... );
      ...
      message.flip();
      sock.send( new DatagramPacket( message.array(), message.limit(), dst ));
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not mandatory. IP will choose an interface based on the routing tables to the destination.

Answer (score 2):

You can't bind to the broadcast address. The question doesn't make sense. You don't need to bind at all for sending, and for receiving you should bind to 0.0.0.0 in most circumstances.