# Android broadcast to 255.255.255.255 not working

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, broadcast

I've been searching on the internet for some solutions o my problem, but I simply can't make the `255.255.255.255` broadcast work.

```
        String broadip = "255.255.255.255";
        DatagramSocket socket= new DatagramSocket(PORT);
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(broadip);
        socket.setReuseAddress(true);
        socket.setBroadcast(true);
        InetSocketAddress sAddress = new InetSocketAddress(broadip, PORT);
        socket.bind(sAddress);

        int length = this.buffer.length;
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(this.buffer, length,address,PORT);
        socket.send(packet);
        socket.close();
```

When it gets to the `socket.bind(sAddress)` line, it throws an exception **"failed to bind"**. I also tried to "skip" this bind line, the socket sends the packet but the other machines never receive this packet.

Strangely the code below works just fine, but only sends the packet to `192.168.25.8`, and I need a broadcast instead:

```
        String broadip = "192.168.25.8";
        DatagramSocket socket= new DatagramSocket(PORT);
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName(broadip);
        socket.setReuseAddress(true);
        socket.setBroadcast(true);

        int length = this.buffer.length;
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(this.buffer, length,address,PORT);
        socket.send(packet);
        socket.close();
```

There are the android manifest permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: you can try this ip to broadcast : 172.16.0.0  see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broadcast_address

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15913678/2657100

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: I found my ip broadcast address, 192.168.25.255, but the broadcast is not working anyway. May it be a coding issue? Or because I am running on a Android Emulator?

But when I send the package to 192.168.25.8, another host ip address, that host receives the message just fine.

Comment: @Kaushal28 any ideas?

Comment: @nafas did not work for me

Comment: I think you should try running on actual devices. In emulator you've to port forward.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, instead of using `global broadcast address`(255.255.255.255), use of `Network layer broadcast address` (192.168.25.255 or 192.168.255.255 depends on your subnet) worked perfectly in `UDP` broadcast. See [this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/219764/255-255-255-255-vs-192-168-1-255) for difference between them.

I had this same issue previously, [THIS](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/1252) page suggests use of `Network layer` broadcast address instead of `255.255.255.255` for Android UDP connections.